# GCD implementation of fraction addition not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am following the Runestone Academy Python3 course and tried to implement 'addition' feature for fractions using Class but I am getting error.

When I am not using GCD implementation, the code is running fine

Here is my code:

```
class Fraction:

    def __init__(self, top, bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom

    def show(self):
        print(f'{self.num}/{self.den}')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.num}/{self.den}'

    # adding without GCD implementation

    # def __add__(self,other_fraction):
    #     new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den + self.den * other_fraction.num
    #     new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den

    #     return Fraction(new_num, new_den)

    # adding with GCD implementation

    def gcd(self, m, n):
        while m % n != 0:
            m, n = n, m % n

        return n

    def __add__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den + self.den * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        common = gcd(new_num, new_den)

        return Fraction(new_num // common, new_den // common)

    # my attempt of adding two fractions by creating a method 'add'

    # def add(self,other_fraction):
    #     new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den + self.den * other_fraction.num
    #     new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den

    #     return Fraction(new_num, new_den)


# my_fraction = Fraction(3,5)
# print(my_fraction)
# print(f'I ate {my_fraction} of my pizza')
# my_fraction.__str__()
# str(my_fraction)

f1 = Fraction(1, 4)
f2 = Fraction(1, 2)
f3 = f1 + f2
# f3 = f1.add(f2)
print(f3)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Mosh_Lec/app.py", line 74, in <module>
    f3 = f1 + f2
  File "D:/Python/Mosh_Lec/app.py", line 53, in __add__
    common = gcd(new_num, new_den)
NameError: name 'gcd' is not defined
```

I also tried with this variation but same error:

```
    def gcd(self, m, n):
        self.num = m
        self.den = n
        while self.num % self.den != 0:
            self.num, self.den = self.den, self.num % self.den

        return self.den
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcd method should not logically be part of the Fraction class. Indeed, you can call the gcd method with any two numbers, they do not need to be the numerator and denominator of a fraction. Therefore I would move the gcd function outside of the class.

```
def gcd(m, n):
    ...

class Fraction:
    ...
```

Comment: If it is just used by class `Fraction`, I think move it in class as a static function and add a underline is also a good idea.

Comment: @Riccardo Thanks! It helped. I am completely new to oop and still wrapping my head around all the abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at there:

```
NameError: name 'gcd' is not defined
```

It means that it cannot find the function(or method) named `gcd`. Of course! It need to be called with a `Fraction` object, so try to change your source code at line `32`:

```
-         common = gcd(new_num, new_den)
+         common = self.gcd(new_num, new_den)
```

`self` is a Fraction `object`.

By the way, the method `gcd` that do not use the parament `self` should be defined as a static function:

```py
class Fraction:
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def _gcd(m: int, n: int):
        ...

    ...
```

And call the method by `Fraction._gcd` (the underline means that it is private function(or method)).

Comment: Thanks! It's my first attempt at oop.

Answer (score 1):

See it's a simple issue if u see the error:

> ```
> File "D:/Python/Mosh_Lec/app.py", line 53, in __add__
> common = gcd(new_num, new_den) 
> NameError: name 'gcd' is not defined
> ```

you will see that you have defined **gcd** but why it is saying GCD, not defined here's the reason:

> ```
> common = self.gcd(new_num, new_den)
> ```

It is as simple as that just put the above code like this:

> ```
>  def __add__(self, other_fraction):
>     new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den + self.den * other_fraction.num
>     new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
>     common = self.gcd(new_num, new_den)
>
>     return Fraction(new_num // common, new_den // common)
> ```

and your problem is solved! Kudos!

It as simple as that.......